# Como hacer operaciones en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la tabla vales con los campos folio_vale, importe, otra tabla comprobantes con los siguientes campos, folio_vale, importe, pueden ser muchas facturas para un vale ejemplo

```
Vales
folio =  1, importe = 5000

comprobantes
folio = 1, importe = 500
folio = 1, importe = 1650
folio = 1, importe = 350
```

quiero sumar los comprobantes y restarlos al importe de vales en MYSQL pero no tengo idea como funciona el SUM, ojala puedan ayudarme

Comment: Trata de construir alguna query sobre la cual podamos ayudarte

Comment: Puedes empezar por [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp)

Comment: SELECT cv.folio_vale,cv.importe,cv.estatus,ec.importe,ec.estatus,ec.depto_responsable,SUM(ec.importe) AS total_adeudo, SUM(cv.importe) AS fin FROM egresos_caja AS ec LEFT JOIN comprobacion_vale AS cv ON cv.folio_vale=ec.folio_vale WHERE ec.depto_responsable = '20' AND ec.estatus ='1'

Comment: PAra usar un sum, tenes que usar un group by.. leiste la documentacion al respecto?

Comment: @gbianchi guarda con ese comentario, yo lo quitaría porque uno podría utilizar un **SUM** en un **SELECT** sin necesidad de la clausula **GROUP BY**. **SUM** se puede utilizar al igual que se utiliza **COUNT** y **AVG**

Comment: @andres y si nos compartes alguna fuente al respecto de tu afirmación?

Comment: Cualquier función de agregacion se puede usar sobre una tabla, si es la unica o unicas columnas en el select. Entonces aunque cierto,  no son los casos mas comunes.

Comment: Tal cual no es el caso mas comun, pero tu afirmación no es del todo correcta y por eso deberias corregirla, pero queda en vos eso. Como bien dice [esta documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) comunmente se utiliza con **GROUP BY**. Disculpen la fuente, la verdad esto lo aprendí de libros

Answer (score 0):

No es lo mas lindo que he hecho pero lo podes resolver de esta manera.

```sql
SELECT c.folio
  (SUM(c.importe) - v.importe) AS Diferencia
FROM comprobantes c INNER JOIN folio_vales v ON c.folio = v.folio
GROUP BY c.folio
```

Por si queres probar que anda lo hice ejecutando este código

```sql
SELECT ProductID,
  SUM(Quantity) AS tot1,
  SUM(Quantity) AS tot2,
  (SUM(Quantity) + SUM(Quantity)) AS TOTAL 
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY ProductID
```

en [esta base de w3shool](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_sum)

Comment: De forma online existen mejores plataformas para testear consultas sql como [esta](https://dbfiddle.uk/), por otro lado que tal si le agregas al OP una explicación dado que según su pregunta no sabe hacerlo, así no solo le das el código sino además le enseñas como y por que quedó así

Comment: Me explico tengo rato atorado con este problema
Tabla: egresos_caja
folio_vale,depto_responsable,importe

SELECT eg.folio_vale,eg.importe, SUM(CASE WHEN eg.depto_responsable = '20' THEN eg.importe ELSE 0 END) suma, SUM(CASE WHEN cv.estatus='1' THEN cv.importe ELSE 0 END) comp FROM egresos_caja AS eg LEFT JOIN comprobacion_vale AS cv ON eg.folio_vale = cv.folio_vale WHERE eg.estatus='1'
me suma todos los vales no solo lo del departamento 20